# Retrieving highscore files to a PyInstaller-created .exe

Tags: python, pygame, pyinstaller

I made a game in Python and converted it to a single executable file using PyInstaller. The problem is that it can't save highscores permanently: it can save and display them during a run, but since the highscore files are extracted to a temporary folder the aren't saved for after the run. What do I have to do in order to permanently save the highscores?

Comment: `pickle` is in the Python standard library so it doesn't require any installation.

Comment: Sorry! I was convinced it was the whole time. Never mind...

Answer (score 2):

Use Pickle: https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html

Dump the highscore list to a file on the users computer along side the executable.

```
import pickle
highscore = 100
pickle.dump(highscore, open('highscore.pkl', 'wb'))
```

Then when your program first opens, unpickle that same file into your highscores list.

```
try:
    highscore = pickle.load(open('highscore.pkl', 'rb'))
except IOError:
    highscore = 0
```

The error handler will catch the load incase the file can't be found and set `highscore` to 0

If you want, you can have your game create a folder like C:/Program Files/YourGame and change the location of highscore.pkl to that folder.  This way, no matter where the user puts the executable, it will always be able to find the highscore.

The code in this example won't create a directory and that is a little out of the scope of this question, so look elsewhere for that if you need.

Comment: I was hoping there would be a simpler solution than installing another module to be honest. This will probably take me another good while to pick up, but I'll definitely give it a shot and hopefully it will make everything work in the end. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @MMM Pickle is part of the standard library, you shouldn't have to install anything new.

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance, I was convinced it involved an extra download and installation. However, I looked it up and it seems to me that pickle is simply a different way of reading and writing files which is mostly what I was already doing - are you sure it will permanently save highscores that way? The idea of creating a folder with files in it, on the other hand, actually seems more like the solution to me - the only problem is that it would easily enable the user to give themselves any score they like and part of why I make everything into an .exe is trying to prevent that.